Where did the live preview go?
So after a few years of no developement, I have started again with a UIKit Storyboard project - and I remember it was possible to preview a live view of the Storyboard View Controller, like this:
(Random image from Google)


Is this somehow possible to do? I have been searching a while but haven't found a solution.

Are you sure it's UIKit instead of SwiftUI?

@sonle Yes, I'm using UIKit and have always been using UIKit.

Yes, they abolished that, along with IBDesignable and other stuff that required the storyboard to be "compiled" for display. It was never very reliable anyway.
If you want to test your autolayout constraints against difference sizes of device, that's still available by clicking the name of the current device, at the bottom; and the other buttons let you switch to dark mode, change orientation, change accessibility content size, etc. Thus you can do almost everything here that the "live" preview allowed you to do:

The one thing that's really missing here is that you can no longer show multiple screen sizes / orientations simultaneously. Plus the whole size-class-variant interface is gone ("trait variations", I've complained about that separately).
